# Issue with Proguard when keep class of android library

Tags: android, android-proguard

I want to use Proguard for application. I am using `com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton` as library so I want to exclude the same.

I have enabled the proguard in my `build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And in `proguard-rules.pro` file, I added below line:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton {
     public *;
 }
```

But the library is getting obfuscated and in the apk of my application, actual code and obfuscated code are both present.

Can someone tell me if I am missing something in the `proguard-rules.pro`?

Comment: -keep        class com.melnykov.fab.** { *; }    add that

Comment: @RobertRowntree you should post your comment as an answer to help other devs which come here ;)